# How do I do the following with iMovie?

Tags: imovie

I am trying to do a few things with iMovie, and unable to figure it out.

1. I marked different places in the video with a "Marker". Is there a way for me to select anything between two specific markers?
2. I am trying to move to a specific point in the movie. This turns out to be difficult with the mouse! It keeps jumping within 20 seconds of where I want to put the marker, or go to. Is there a way to go to a precise place in the movie?
3. Is there a way to add a fade-in/fade-out between clips (not for the whole movie as in Settings on the right upper corner of the clips)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, iMovies' user interface is largely [inscrutable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inscrutable). Perhaps that's because it caters to a video editor's workflow - something that's largely foreign to me. Anyway, this won't be a detailed answer, but hopefully enough to inch you forward.

1. The main thing I've noticed with markers is that they are like magnets: when the pointer is close by, it seems to "snap" to the marker. The only real use I've ever found for them is that they can be inserted during video playback (<kbd>M</kbd>). This is useful if you're looking for a place to cut a video, or make a splice to insert something. [Here's another take on it.](https://macmost.com/using-imovie-markers.html)
2. Try using the "Precision Editor" (in the iMovie menu bar: `Window->Show Precision Editor` while a clip is selected in the editing panel. It may also help to "zoom in" (make the clip longer) using the slider in the upper right-hand corner of the editing area). [Cf](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2191412)
3. Yes. The way I use this is as follows:

   - Split the clip (`iMovie->Modify->Split Clip`) at your chosen point.
   - drag one of the Transitions from the palette to the edit area in between the segments of the split clip
   - adjust the length/time of the transition with a double-click on the transition in the edit area

The picture shows the sequence, but you may have to view it full size to see the details.

[image]

Again - I'm no expert; you'll learn more, and quicker, by searching for help on the Internet. And keep looking! Some of the most useful features in iMovie are well-hidden: I think the ["Ken Burns Effect"](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/10/11/use-remove-ken-burns-effect-imovie/) may be the best of these hidden features.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "drag one of the Transitions from the palette to the edit area in between the segments of the split clip". What is the palette area and what is the edit area?

Comment: @kloop: see added graphic

Comment: @kloop: Hope it helped. If so, [please read this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).